# Can't connect to Wi-Fi with nmcli, “mismatching interface name”

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, manjaro

Today when I woke up I found that I couldn't connect to any WiFi, although the WiFi functioned well on my other devices, and the network manager just shows a blank page.

I tried to connect with `nmcli connection up <network name>`, and it threw the following error:

> Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection (device enp2s0 not available because profile is not compatible with device (mismatching interface name)

Does anyone know what the error is? I tried to search for it, but I couldn't find any helpful information, and also the only package I installed recently is [rslsync](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Resilio_Sync), but I don't think it would affect anything? I tried to stop the service `rslsync.service`, but it didn't help.

I am using Manjaro KDE 21.0.5 with Linux kernel 5.12.2. My nmcli version is 1.30.4-3.